# Get all annotations of another class inside scala macro annotation

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros

I'm trying to write an annotation for case classes to dynamically add methods for getting MongoDB Document instance. Everything works fine, except the situation of nested case classes:

```
@MongoEntity
final case class Person(name: String, info: DetailedInfo)

@MongoEntity
final case class DetailedInfo(info: String)
```

The reason of that is annotations method always return empty collection. In the snippet below accessors method return types using c.typecheck function.

```
def generateMethods(classType: TypeName, fields: List[ValDef]) = {
  val typedFields = accessors(fields)

  q"""
    ${Modifiers(Flag.IMPLICIT)} def toDoc(model: $classType): org.mongodb.scala.Document = {
      org.mongodb.scala.Document(
        ..${typedFields.map {
          // annotations is always empty =(
          case accessor if accessor.symbol.asType.annotations.exists(_.eq(MongoEntity)) => q"""${accessor.name.toString} -> ${accessor.name}.toDoc(model.${accessor.name})"""
          case accessor if accessor.paramType <:< typeOf[TraversableLike[_, _]] => q"""${accessor.name.toString} -> model.${accessor.name}.toList"""
          case accessor => q"""${accessor.name.toString} -> model.${accessor.name}"""
        }}
      )
    }
   """
}
```

How can I get the list of annotations of another case class ?

Comment: Currently. the least boilerplate solution that I found is to introduce new marker annotation for types, that should be mapped to Document. This annotation can be obtained using pattern matching on ValDef class through Modifiers.